# How do I store and retrieve Tensors in a global namespace in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to read a big Tensorflow project. For a project that the nodes of the computation graph are scattered around the project, I wonder if there is a way to store a Tensor node of the computation graph and add that node to the fetch list in sess.run?

For example, if I want to add probs at line 615 of 
https://github.com/allenai/document-qa/blob/master/docqa/nn/span_prediction.py to a global namespace, is there a method like tf.add_node(probs, "probs"), and later I could get tf.get_node("probs"), just for the sake of conveniently passing node around the project.

A more general question would be, what will be a better idea to structure the tensorflow code and improve the efficiency of experimenting with different models.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. To retrieve it later, you'll have to give it a name so that you can retrieve it by name. Take `probs` in your code as an example. It's created with `tf.nn.softmax()` function, the API for which is shown below.

```
tf.nn.softmax(
    logits,
    axis=None,
    name=None,
    dim=None
)
```

See the parameter `name`? You can add this parameter to line 615 like this:

```
 probs = tf.nn.softmax(all_logits, name='my_tensor')
```

Later when you need it, you can call `tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name(name)` to retrieve this tensor.

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
retrieved_probs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('my_tensor:0')
```

`'my_tensor'` is the name of the *softmax* operation, and ':0' should be added to the end of it meaning that you're retrieving the tensor instead of the operation. When calling `Graph.get_operation_by_name()`, no ':0' should be added.

You'll have to make sure that the tensor exists(it might be created in the code executed before this line, or it might be restored from a meta graph file). If it's created in a variable scope, you'll also have to add the scope name and a '/' in the front of the `name` param. For example, `'my_scope/my_tensor:0'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found that I should use graph.get_operation_by_name("my_tensor") in this case.

Comment: You are right, but I find that I need to do graph.get_tensor_by_name('my_tensor:0') to get it.

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake.